# Manual COPY INTO works but Scheduled Task does not

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to understand a problem I am having with scheduling tasks in Snowflake.

Currently, I have an AWS s3 bucket with csv files in it. The task reads the data in the s3 bucket and does a `COPY INTO` the target table. The task itself works if I run it manually. Rows are added to the table. However, if I schedule the same task to run, it does so but no new rows are added to the table.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is?

The task is structed as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK "TASK_NAME"
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 30 7 * * * Europe/Berlin' 
WAREHOUSE = "WAREHOUSE"
AS
COPY INTO TABLE_NAME
FROM @"STAGE"
pattern='STRING'
file_format = (type = csv, field_delimiter = ';', SKIP_HEADER = 1)
ON_ERROR = CONTINUE;
```

Edit: The task is set to run and not suspended.

Comment: Because the files are already copied? Do you see the COPY query in the query_history or in load_history?

Comment: 1.Did manually copying files first time , and may be file did not copy when you schedule it .Look into query history .
2.Did executor  of task has enough privileges set  like EXECUTE MANAGED TASK ? 
3.After task is created , it  will  be in suspend state and need to explicit start.
4.Do you see anything in TASK_HISTORY (select *
  from table(information_schema.task_history())
  order by scheduled time;)
5.Try to change cron schedule to run frequently for every 5 mins , to see something getting into task history.
6.Finally , delete task and recreate new one with account admin and check.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas from me:

1. You triggered manually (due to testing) and then the task triggers the COPY again. But, since the file was already loaded, the file is not loaded again.
2. Tasks run with the privileges of the task owner, manual COPY INTO-statements with the role of the current context - is there a possible conflict?

What are TASK_HISTORY (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_history.html) and QUERY_HISTORY (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html) showing?